# State.get(...) is undefined when overriding sw-order-create component

Tags: vue.js, shopware, shopware6

**Customer request:**

In the initial Modal window for creating a new order from administration, he already wants/needs to be able to add a customer comment, while creating the order. In default you can only edit the customer comment, after the order has already been saved.

**My plan:**

My plan was/is to have an extra store/state for saving the customerComment, because the `SwOrderState` is set to `const` and can't be overriden.

*Shopware Version: 6.5.7.2*

**My error:**

Browser console says: `[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: State.get(...) is undefined"`

**My code:**

In my plugin i have the following file for overriding `sw-order-create` in path `custom/plugins/NcThemeExtension/src/Resources/app/administration/src/module/sw-order/page/sw-order-create/index.ts`:

```
import additionalOrderState from '../../state/additional.order.store';

const { Context, State, Mixin } = Shopware;
const { Criteria } = Shopware.Data;

export default Shopware.Component.wrapComponentConfig({
    inject: ['repositoryFactory', 'feature'],

    created(): void {
        console.log("Override successfully injected");
        this.createdComponent();
    },

    beforeCreate(): void {
        State.registerModule('swOrder', swOrderState);
        State.registerModule('additionalOrder', additionalOrderState);
    },

    methods: {
        unregisterModule(): void {
            State.unregisterModule('swOrder');
            State.unregisterModule('additionalOrder');
        },

        saveFinish(): void {
            console.log("saveFinish()");
            console.log("orderId: " + this.orderId)

            if (!this.orderId) {
                return;
            }

            console.log("customerComment: " + State.get('additionalOrder').customerComment);

            this.isSaveSuccessful = false;
            void this.$router.push({ name: 'sw.order.detail', params: { id: this.orderId } });

        },
    }
});
```

In another path `/custom/plugins/NcThemeExtension/src/Resources/app/administration/src/module/sw-order/state/additional.order.store.ts` i got this file:

```
// @ts-ignore
import type { Module } from 'vuex';

// @ts-ignore
const { Service } = Shopware;

interface AdditionalOrderState {
    customerComment: string
}

// @ts-ignore
const AdditionalOrderStore: Module<AdditionalOrderState, VuexRootState> = {
    namespaced: true,

    state: (): AdditionalOrderState => ({
        customerComment: ''
    }),

    mutations: {
        setCustomerComment(state: AdditionalOrderState, customerComment: string) {
            state.customerComment = customerComment;
        },
    },
};

/**
 * @private
 */
export default AdditionalOrderStore;

/**
 * @private
 */
export type {
    AdditionalOrderState,
};
```

Both files are imported in the main.js like this:

```
Shopware.Component.register('sw-order-create', () => import('./module/sw-order/page/sw-order-create'));

import './module/sw-order/page/sw-order-create-details';
```

*Note: Of course i have an extra .html.twig file for adding the textarea-field itself, but this is such basic and works so i didn't want to add more code to this question as it is already.*